# Make List Sections non-collapsible in SwiftUI when embedded into a NavigationView SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationview

When I embed a `List` grouped into `Section`s into a `NavigationView` the section headers become collapsible. I'd like to keep them non-collapsible, just like when the `List` is not embedded into the `NavigationView`.

My current code (with the NavigationView):

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct MyGroup {
    var name:String, items:[String]
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var groups : [MyGroup] = [
        .init(name: "Animals", items: ["","","","","","","",""]),
        .init(name: "Vehicles", items: ["","","","","","","","⛵️"])]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List {
                    ForEach(groups, id: \.self.name) { group in
                        Section(header: Text(group.name)) {
                            ForEach(group.items, id:\.self) { item in
                                Text(item)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.navigationTitle("collections")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[image: list with collapsible sections]

Comment: As of today it is not possible in iOS. Not even via UIKit. It is only possible with `.collapsible(false)` on macOS. File a bug with Apple if you want this to change in the future.

Comment: Putting the List inside the  VStack makes it collapsable.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It is default style applied, you can make it explicitly set for `List` like below (tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14)

[image: demo]

```
    List {
        ForEach(groups, id: \.self.name) { group in
            Section(header: Text(group.name)) {
                ForEach(group.items, id:\.self) { item in
                    Text(item)
                }
            }
        }
    }.listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle()) // or GroupedListStyle
```

Comment: This is not working if the list is embedded in a NavigationView

Comment: @Daniel It works fine for list embedded in NavigationView. I verified in XCode 13.2 and iOS 15.2.

Comment: Works for me, Xcode 14.1 (14B47b)

Answer (score 6):

As of iOS 17, Sections are no longer collapsible (on Xcode 15b2).

To enable collapse/expand behavior:

```
public init(isExpanded: Binding<Bool>, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content, @ViewBuilder header: () -> Parent)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Will be really hard to find out why its not working anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Just using the SidebarListStyle in listStyle modifier

```
.listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
```

Comment: This is not working if the list is embedded in a NavigationView

Comment: This is funny because using .sidebar doesnt make it work, but it does what i want (remove the extra top space probably used for animation scrolling in grouping section headers)

Answer (score 3):

In case you're stumbling on this... The issue doesn't have anything to do with being embedded in a NavigationView as the OP and [@Danial](https://stackoverflow.com/users/345258/daniel) mentioned. It's because it's embedded in the the VStack at the first level of the NavigationView in the example code. Seems like a SwiftUI bug to me.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across the same problem and none of the suggested solutions worked for me. And contrary to some comments, this **is indeed related to `Lists` embedded inside `NavigationViews`** as I could reproduce the problem even after removing my `VStack`. The only solution that worked for me was setting the `navigationViewStyle` to stack:

```swift
.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
```